# Avoid duplicate object files using subdir structure with qmake

Tags: c++, qt, project, qmake, object-files

I have a game with two separate projects for the application itself and the tests. I'm building all of the projects in-source. Here's a shortened version of my project structure:

```
game
    game.pro
    app
        app.pro
        Entity.h
        Entity.cpp
        Entity.o
        moc_Entity.cpp
        moc_Entity.o
    tests
        layer
            layer.pro
            Entity.o (duplicated)
            moc_Entity.cpp (duplicated)
            moc_Entity.o (duplicated)
            tst_Layer.cpp
```

**app.pro:**

```
QT += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4) {
    QT += widgets
}

TARGET = cotw-clone
TEMPLATE = app

MOC_DIR = .moc
OBJECTS_DIR = .obj

HEADERS += MainWindow.h \
    Map.h \
    Tile.h \
    Character.h \
    Layer.h \
    NewGameDialog.h \
    GameController.h \
    Stair.h \
    Random.h \
    MapGenerator.h \
    TileData.h \
    Statistics.h \
    StatisticsDialog.h \
    StatisticWidget.h \
    Range.h \
    Level.h \
    RandomMapGenerator.h \
    AiController.h \
    MonsterJournalWidget.h \
    InventoryDialog.h \
    PathSearch.h \
    PathNode.h \
    Path.h \
    Geometry.h \
    EntityDatabase.h \
    EntityData.h \
    Entity.h \
    CharacterData.h \
    EntityMetadata.h

SOURCES +=\
    MainWindow.cpp \
    Map.cpp \
    Tile.cpp \
    Character.cpp \
    Layer.cpp \
    NewGameDialog.cpp \
    GameController.cpp \
    Stair.cpp \
    TileData.cpp \
    Statistics.cpp \
    StatisticsDialog.cpp \
    StatisticWidget.cpp \
    Level.cpp \
    RandomMapGenerator.cpp \
    AiController.cpp \
    MonsterJournalWidget.cpp \
    InventoryDialog.cpp \
    PathSearch.cpp \
    PathNode.cpp \
    Path.cpp \
    EntityDatabase.cpp \
    EntityData.cpp \
    Entity.cpp \
    CharacterData.cpp \
    main.cpp

FORMS += MainWindow.ui \
    NewGameDialog.ui \
    StatisticsDialog.ui \
    StatisticWidget.ui \
    MonsterJournalWidget.ui \
    InventoryDialog.ui

RESOURCES += \
    icons/icons.qrc \
    tiles/tiles.qrc

RESOURCES += \
    entities/entities.qrc
```

My problem is that all of the `tests` projects use classes from the `app` project, which means they're compiling all of these classes even though they've already been compiled when `app` was built. Take the `layer` test project, for example:

**layer.pro:**

```
QT += testlib
QT -= gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4) {
    QT += widgets
}

TARGET = tst_LayerTest
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += tst_LayerTest.cpp
DEFINES += SRCDIR=\\\"$$PWD/\\\"

HEADERS += "../../app/Entity.h"
SOURCES += "../../app/Entity.cpp"
```

So how can I point qmake to the `.o` (and `qrc_`, `.moc` etc.) files that have already been produced in `app`? Is there some qmake variable for this purpose, or is my project structure just fundamentally flawed?

Comment: It looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644643/how-to-add-object-files-to-a-project-in-qt) answers my question, but am interested to know if there's an easier way than specifying each `.obj` file.

Comment: Does [this answer, using wildcard *](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9464075/104370) help?

Comment: I had thought about doing that, but was unsure of what would happen with regards to `.o` files that would get linked but not used.. would that slow down my build significantly?

Comment: It's hard to say, with the amount of info supplied,  but I doubt it. Why not just try it, and see if it works?

Comment: It works fine, except that the wildcard includes `main.o`, which causes multiple definitions of `'main'` to be found. Is there a way to exclude certain files or patterns?

Comment: Sure. I've added an answer, with an example of how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wildcards in qmake .pro files, to save having to maintain a list of all file names.

For example,

```
SOURCES += *.cpp
```

Each time you run qmake, that pattern `*.cpp` gets expanded in to the current list of files matching the pattern.

You can also use `-=` to remove file names, if you have a particular filename that you wish to exclude.

For example:

```
SOURCES += *.cpp
SOURCES -= main.cpp
```

**Edit**

I almost suggested in my earlier answer that you introduce a library, using qt's lib template, to contain your common code.

Then your build structure would look like this - assuming that you can move files around, from app/ to lib/:

```
game
    game.pro
    app
        app.pro
        main.cpp
    lib
        lib.pro
        Entity.h
        Entity.cpp
        Entity.o
        moc_Entity.cpp
        moc_Entity.o
    tests
        layer
            layer.pro
            tst_Layer.cpp
```

You can find some info on library projects in ["Building a Library" on the Qt website](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qmake-common-projects.html#building-a-library)

If, for some reason, you can't move your files around, then you can introduce a new directory for the library, and have it pull in source files from the app directory - but that is definitely more faff, and more confusing:

```
game
    game.pro
    app
        app.pro - builds only main.o
        main.cpp
        Entity.h
        Entity.cpp
        moc_Entity.cpp
    lib
        lib.pro
        Entity.o
        moc_Entity.o
    tests
        layer
            layer.pro
            tst_Layer.cpp
```

**Edit 2**

One problem you have is you are putting object files in to the LIBS variable, which defines what libraries your code will link against. So that'll be why you are getting errors with those files.

Try changing those LIBS uses to OBJECTS instead, and it may work.

If not, have a read of this [thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-48959.html), which is asking pretty much the same thing.

In particular, see the answer by  ChrisW67 of '13th May 2012, 10:14' which begins;

> Try:
>
> OBJECTS += f1.o f2.o f3.o f3.o
>
> although I think that, if you have the source, building it into your
>   app directly or via a library is a better option.

Comment: A-ha! That would make sense. Thanks. :)

Comment: Note that you have to have `app` listed before `tests` in `game.pro`, otherwise the build will fail, as the `.o` files it depends on from `app` will not yet be generated.

Comment: Hmm.. `LIBS += "../../app/.obj/*.o" LIBS -= "../../app/.obj/main.o"` still gives me `multiple definition of 'main'`.

Comment: I'm confused. You didn't mention LIBS before. Please could you add a complete .pro file to your quesiotns, so that we can understand what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, I've added `app.pro` to my question.

I'd rather not create a separate library if I an avoid it, but it might come to it.

Comment: I get the error when building any project which links to the `.o` files, e.g.: http://pastebin.com/vz8PrhJR

Comment: I just ended up using a library; much easier. :p Thanks.